# CSS Media Query not workig - Attempting to load two diff. style sheets based on browser width

Tags: html, css, browser, width, media-queries

So I'm using two media queries on my page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 1099px)" href="./src/css/narrow.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1100px)" href="./src/css/main.css" />
```

The main.css one loads by default, but when the browser is re-sized below 1100px, it simply loads no stylesheet, therefor the entire page renders no styling.

Anybody have any clue what I'm doing wrong? Also, isn't it possible to use media queries inside of "main.css"? So I can only alter certain elemnts based on browser width, instead of loading a whole new stylesheet? Thanks much guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep you can do this all in the main stylesheet, so something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1099px){
 /* css here */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px){
 /* css here */
}
```

Actually I also noticed you had max-**device**-width: on so this will only target ipads/iphones etc which is probably why you weren't seeing this stylesheet on the desktop

Comment: Update: Using your advice, this is what I've come up with. My design looks great until it reaches about 700px width in browser, so I've configured it to load narrow.css on desktops when width < 700px, and on any device width < 1200px. Does a setup such as this sound correct and efficient to cover both desktop users of any resolution & mobile devices in both portrait & landscape mode. [Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/F2CP8hrw)

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to use Javascript/Jquery to detect the screen size and load a different stylesheet based on that screen size, but Adam's solution is probably better unless you need to separate your style sheets for a particular reason.

This article will give you all the information you need using jquery - http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use multiple queries - I make a new one every time I fine a width that doesn't look quite right.

```
@media (max-width:319px) {
 // styles
}
@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:479px) {
 // styles
}
@media (min-width:480px) and (max-width:479px) {
 //styles
}
etc..., etc...
```

I'll also usually built the queries on each element that needs them.  I find that when you put ALL your rules for the a media query in one section of your stylesheet things get confusing to maintain.

For example:

```
div.box {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (...) {
  width: 80%;
}
@media (...) {
  width: 60%;
}
etc...
```

Then on another element that needs resizing I'll do the same thing:

```
div.otherbox {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (...) {
  width: 80%;
}
@media (...) {
  width: 60%;
}
etc...
```